# c# calling value from another page

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

Working on a windows 8 store app, so I've managed to pass a parameter to another page, but how do I call it on the other page?

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Test), Testbutton);


    }
```

As you can see Testbutton is what I am passing, so on another page I want to call it, then on a button click I will disable the button. The disable button part I know how to do.

Comment: So, you want to pass a button object in to a new page which you are navigating to so that something in the new page can press the button which does something and disables the button? If this is the case, you should really look into using MVVM. In this way, you can create a `ButtonState` property which the button binds to. Then, you don't need to worry about passing in the actual button, you just update the state in the `ViewModel` and the button will respond properly. Then, you do button 'clicks' via an `ICommand`, such as `RelayCommand` (in Mvvm Light).

Comment: in the OnNavigatedTo event use Testbutton btn= e.Parameter as Testbutton;